# Figuring out if IP addresses are public or private for use in chef recipes

Tags: chef-infra, opensolaris, recipe, smartos

I'm using Chef to automate deployment of various SmartOS zones.  I'm trying to figure out what the correct way of determining if a network interface has a public or private address and keeping track of that.  For generic Apache Listen and NameVirtualHost directives the following is sufficient:

```
ips = []
links = %x{dladm show-vnic -o link | grep -v LINK}.strip.split("\n")
links.each do |link|
  ips << %x{ifconfig #{link} | grep inet | awk '{ print $2 }'}.strip
end
```

For ipfilter rules I need to have two different classes of rules.  Rules that get applied to public interfaces and then apply a different set to private interfaces.  Should I be passing all the interfaces to chef via the json configuration file rather than figuring it out inside recipes?

Comment: I could not tag it with SmartOS which is the Illumos fork of OpenSolaris which I am using.

Comment: I retagged the question for you.

Answer (score 0):

ohai generates attribute data at runtime.

in particular you may be interested in

`$ sudo ohai network/interfaces`

and the related

`node["network"]["interfaces"]`

You will still have to reject RFC1918 inet4 addresses and check the link scope is global for inet6